# Pycharm recognizes kwargs in print as wrong (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Whenever I do something like this:

```
print("Hello World", flush=True, file=sys.stderr)
```

PyCharm complains about

```
End of statement expected
Statement expected, found Py:DEDENT
Statement expected, found Py:RPAR
```

Because of that "Syntax Error" all definitions after that are buggy and displayed as wrong as well.

That confuses me a lot and features (e.g. autocompletion) are not working anymore because of this.

Is there any setting I did not set correctly? Is this a bug?

Comment: Can't reproduce this even with a python 2.7 and *from __future__ import print_function*. What PyCharm version do you have and which python interpreter have you chosen in project?

Comment: I definitely have to check the python interpreter. Thanks!

Comment: That was it. It was still on 2.7. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My settings for the python interpreter were wrong.
To change it, I went to `Settings->Project->Project Interpreter`.
Everything is working fine now!

Thanks for the comments which leads to the solution!